# ANTLR match identifier but not reserved keywords

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4, identifier

I am trying to match complex numbers using different notations, one of them using the `cis` function as such : MODULUS `cis` PHASE

The problem is that my identifier rule matches the `cis` as well as the start of the number following it and since it's bigger than the `CIS` token itself it always returns an identifier token type. How could i avoid that ?

Here's the grammar :

```
grammar Sandbox;

input : number? CIS UNSIGNED 
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;

number : FLOAT
    | UFLOAT 
    | UINT
    | INT
    ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

UFLOAT : UINT (DOT UINT? | 'f') ;
FLOAT : SUB UFLOAT ;
UINT : DIGITS ;
INT : SUB UINT ;
UNSIGNED : UFLOAT 
    | UINT 
    ;
DIGITS : DIGIT+ ;

// Specific lexer rules
CIS : 'cis' ;
SUB : '-' ; 
DOT : '.' ;
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;  // has to be after complex so i or cis doesn't match this first
```

Edit:
The input i was trying to parse with is the complex `1+i` but using it's respective modulus and phase like this : `1.4142135623730951cis0.7853981633974483`

And my actual problem is that the *IDENTIFIER* rule matches `cis0` instead of just matching the *CIS* lexer rule even though it's defined before it.

I vaguely know that ANTLR chooses the rule based on the biggest match, but in this case i want to avoid that =o.

Comment: Not the main problem, but the `+` in `[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ahh that's actually true, since only the first character has that restriction, right ? =O Thanks i'll fix that

Comment: In `MODULUS cis PHASE` are `MODULUS` and `PHASE` identifiers or numbers?  Show an ***actual*** example of input that is being parsed incorrectly.  Also, I believe your grammar has a lot of issues.  For example, `IMAGINARY : IM UNSIGNED?` matches, for example  `i 3`.

Comment: yes exactly, basically they can be either floats or integers, but the only difference is that if it's the imaginary part it has to be unsigned so that the +/- is taken care of before that (i think). Here's one example that i wanted to parse : `1.4142135623730951cis0.7853981633974483`
It's the complex `1 + i` so the modulus and args are those two values respectively

Comment: I removed all the other lexer and parser rules except for the `cis` one to debloat the example

Comment: Does your grammar need to specify that spaces are not needed in `1.4142135623730951cis0.7853981633974483`?  The problem goes away if you require spaces.

Comment: Oh the problem is that i wanted to use this in my own project (simple functional language), where the grammar already ignores whitespace =s

Comment: Ignoring token delimiting whitespace leads to an ambiguous lexer, as you have discovered.

Comment: Oh in that case i guess i will just change the `cis` form notation to something like : `MODULUS 'cis' '(' PHASE ')'`

Thanks for the help !

Comment: @JimGarrison I've been thinking about what you said, instead of just changing the notation ot make it less ambiguous, should i change the whole grammar to include separators at every production rule ? If it makes the grammar better i'll try =O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227745/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-jim-garrison).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions here:

1. Make the complex number a single lexer rule:

```
COMPLEX:  (FLOAT | UFLOAT | UINT | INT) WS* CIS WS* UNSIGNED;
```

which will be longer than an identifier or the pur CIS keyword (and hence matched first).

2. A `cis` secquence is a keyword, when it follows a digit (with optional whitespaces between them), right? So, you could do a lookback (`LA(-1)` in your predicate to reject `cis` as identifier if that condition is true.

I'd prefer solution 1, because the convention is that single entities (and a complex number is, like a float number or a string, a single logicial entity) are match completely in a lexer rule, not in a parser rule.

Comment: Aha, that's a nice trick, I will definitely think about this if i ever have rule precedence issues. I marked this as the answer, but for the second approach, i'm still interested in the lookback, is that the same as a regex lookahead ? Is there a reference where i can read about that too =o

Comment: There's no regex used or supported in ANTLR. But yes, look back is like look ahead, just with a negative offset. There's a function `LA()` in the lexer which you can use to check chars in the input stream relative to the current position. A similar function `LT()` (for look ahead token) exists in the parser to get a specific token relative to the current token position.

Comment: I read the ANTLR reference book and i only reached pages 210~ish for now, so i'm guessing this comes after haha. I will look into `LA` and `LT` since that's something i really wanted to be able to use hehe. Thanks a lot for the help + info !

Answer (score 0):

I'm just putting this here because i think this could be a potential solution, although i'd prefer not having to use semantic predicates because it ties my grammar to a target/specific language =/ (I never used them before so i'm not sure if there's any other caveats too):

```
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* { identifierIsNotReserved() }?;
```

And then we just need to implement the `identifierIsNotReserved` method to check if the identifier rule consumed a reserved keyword, and if so prevent the rule from being applied. And i quote:

> A semantic predicate is a block of arbitrary code in the target language surrounded by {...}?, which evaluates to a boolean value. If the returned value is false, the lexer rule is skipped.

Edit: Forgot to add the reference to where i found this, here it is :
https://riptutorial.com/antlr/example/11237/actions-and-semantic-predicates

Comment: Choosing such a solution would mean you'd reject any identifier from being created that starts with a keyword (you're going to reject `cis0`, right?). Aren't there occurrences where `cis0` (or similar) *is* a valid identifier?

Comment: Wanted to post an answer, but I see Mike already did (and I would've answered something similar to his option 1).